# PHP dropdown now default selection.

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am using php / laravel to extend functionality of an existing site.

There was a selection option form dropdowb to modify results:

```
    $results = [0 => 'Step Failure', 
                1 => 'Success', 
                2 => 'Test Timeout', 
                3 => 'Object Failures',
                4 => 'Maintanence'];
```

Now I want to add a create results section. So that all the above options are selected without the users interaction.

I attempted to just fill the array:

```
    $results = array(1 => 'Success',
                0 => 'Step Failures',
                3 => 'Object Failures',
                2 => 'Test Timeout',
                4 => 'Maintanence');
```

It states selections need to be made.

Comment: How the dropdown is generated?

Comment: A variable passed from a Controller to a JavaScript dropdown box within the view.

Comment: There you have typo mistake, which one is correct `0 => 'Step Failures'` or `0 => 'Step Failure'`? Notice the extra `s`. Is this a multiple select type of dropdown like that of tagging feature, for e.g. see https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#selected-and-disabled-support